# Stage Icon is not visible

Tags: javafx

I am creating a sample code to show the Stage designed in Javafx, It should not have Minimize and Maximize Button only Close ('X') button required.

For that we are using following code.

```
    Stage stage = new Stage(); 
    // Here we have load it using JFXML
     stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    stage.setResizable(true);
    if (title != null && !title.trim().isEmpty()) {
        stage.setTitle(title);
    }
    stage.setWidth(w);
    stage.setHeight(h);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(Dialog.class.getResourceAsStream("/image/myicon.png")));
    stage.showAndWait();
```

Now the icon I set on the stage is not visible.

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume Windows as the OS (in MacOSX the icon is shown). Under Windows, `StageStyle.UTILITY` leads to using `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` in which case the icon is not shown. You probably need to use another StageStyle.

- "PRB: WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW Windows Do Not Show System Menu Icon": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179376